# When trying to change http header using nf_hook .Unable to send ack to a response instead sending tcp retransmission packets

Tags: html, c, networking, linux-kernel, netfilter

Aim:- Writing a kernel module,when inserted does the following things.

1.if a user wants to open a website named "abcde.in" in any browser ,he should get "google.co.in" webpage, in place of "abcde.in" web page.

### Normally accessing google.in i get:-

Observation..(in http header)

302 Moved

The document has moved

HREF=http://www.google.co.in

### :-) next i send an ack And i got the google homepage:-

### With Modification:-

Steps i have taken

a. edited /etc/hosts

```
(google.in IP )     abcde.in
```

So that it gets ip of "google.in"'s for "abcde.in"

b.Next inserting the following piece of module in nf_hook POST_ROUTING implementation

Observation..
i am able to correctly modify and wireshark shows that in reply i am able to get  302 Moved
But i am sending Tcp retransmissions GET / HTTP/1.1. again and again.

I feel i am missing the ack which i need to send as in original case.
why am i unable to send an ack instead of that why i am retransmitting tcp packets to  "GET / HTTP/1.1"

```
if(skb){ 

    liph=(struct iphdr *)skb_network_header(skb);

    if(liph->protocol == 6) {  

    ltcph = (struct tcphdr *)skb_transport_header(skb);
    data=skb->data+(liph->ihl*4) + (ltcph->doff*4);
            datalen=skb->len - ((liph->ihl*4)+(ltcph->doff*4));            
    replace_n=strstr(data,"abcde.in");

            if(replace_n) {

                temp = kmalloc(512 * sizeof(char), GFP_KERNEL);
                memcpy(temp, data, datalen);
                replace_n=strstr(temp,"abcde.in");
                replace_size=strlen("google.in");
                site_diff=replace_size - strlen("abcde.in");
                memmove(replace_n+strlen("abcde.in")+site_diff,replace_n+strlen("abcde.in"),strlen(replace_n)-strlen("abcde.in"));
                memcpy(replace_n,"google.in",strlen("google.in")); 
                skb_put(skb,site_diff);
                memcpy(data,temp,datalen+site_diff);

      liph->tot_len=htons(datalen+site_diff+20+(ltcph->doff*4)); /*modifing necessary fields*/
      liph->check=0;
          liph->check=ip_fast_csum((unsigned char *)liph,liph->ihl);

      int ipl=liph->ihl * 4;
      int ihl=ntohs(liph->tot_len);

         ltcph->check = 0;
     skb->csum = csum_partial(ltcph, ihl - ipl, 0);
     ltcph->check = tcp_v4_check(ihl - ipl,liph->saddr, liph->daddr, skb->csum);
         skb->ip_summed = CHECKSUM_NONE;
```

[Retransmission tck packet wireshark capture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GT1in.png)

Comment: This is a duplicate of [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30269113). Same answer applies.

Comment: But I am not getting RST packet ???